# How to modify nginx access and error log locations with dockerfile?

Tags: docker, nginx, logging, dockerfile, configuration-files

I am running **nginx** in a **docker container**. I have to ***RELOCATE*** the **nginx log files** from `/var/log/nginx/error.log` and `/var/log/nginx/access.log` to different locations. For this I need to modify the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file in my docker image. What can I mention in my **dockerfile** to make this modification?

I do not want to re-write the `nginx.conf` file with commands like `echo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to rewrite using echos, it's easier than that.

- Change the file `nginx.conf` to your needs.
- Put it next to the `Dockerfile`
- Add the following instruction to your Dockerfile: `COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Comment: I feel dumb. Thanks.